# Mongo - add field if object in array of sub docs has value

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

*Details*

I develop survey application with express and struggle with some getting of data.

**The case:**

- you can get all surveys by "GET /surveys". And every survey doc has to contains `hasVoted:mongoose.Bool` and `optionsVote:mongoose.Map` if the user has voted for the survey. (SurveySchema is bellow)
- you can vote for survey by "POST /surveys/vote"
- you can see the results of any survey **only if** you vote for it

```
 new Schema({
    question: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
        required: true,
    },
    options: {
        type: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
            required: true,
        }]
    },
    optionsVote: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Map,
        of: mongoose.Schema.Types.Number,
    },
    votesCount: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Number,
    },
    votes: {
        type: [{
            user: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User',
            },
            option: mongoose.Schema.Types.Number,
        }]
    },
})
```

**Target:**

So the target of the question is how to add fields `hasVoted` and `optionsVote` if there is "Vote" sub document in `votes` array where `user===req.user.id` ?

---

*I believe you got the idea so if you have an idea how to change the schema to achieve the desired result I'm open!*

---

***Example:***

1. Data:

```
[{
 id:"surveyId1
 question:"Question",
 options:["op1","op2"],
 votes:[{user:"userId1", option:0}]
 votesCount:1,
 optionsVote:{"0":1,"1":0}
},{
 id:"surveyId2
 question:"Question",
 options:["op1","op2"],
 votes:[{user:"userId2", option:0}]
 votesCount:1,
 optionsVote:{"0":1,"1":0}
}]
```

2. Route handler:

Where `req.user.id='userId1'` and then make the ***desired*** query.

3. The result

```
[{ // Voted for this survey
 id:"surveyId1
 question:"Question",
 options:["op1","op2"],
 votes:[{user:"userId1", option:0}]
 votesCount:1,
 optionsVote:{"0":1,"1":0},
 hasVoted:true,
},{ // No voted for this survey
 id:"surveyId2
 question:"Question",
 options:["op1","op2"],
 votesCount:1,
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In MongoDB, you can search for sub document as follows

```
//Mongodb query to search for survey filled by a user
db.survey.find({ 'votes.user': myUserId })
```

> So with this when you can get results only where user has voted, do you really need `hasVoted` field?

2. To have `optionsVote` field, first I would prefer schema of `optionsVote` as `{option: "a", count:1}`. You can choose any of the following approach.

   A. manage to update `optionsVote` field at the time of update by incrementing the count of the voted option when you `POST /survey/vote`.

   B. Another approach would be to calculate the `optionsVote` based on `votes` entries at the time of `GET /survey`. You can do this via aggregate

```
//Mongodb query to get optionsVote:{option: "a", count:1} from votes: { user:"x", option:"a"}
db.survey.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$votes" }, 
    { $group: {
        "_id": { "id": "_id", "option": "$votes.option" }, 
       optionCount: { $sum: 1 }
       }
    },
    {
      $group: { "_id": "$_id.id" },
      optionsVote: { $push : { option: "$_id.option", count: "$optionCount" } },
      votes: { $push : '$votes'}
    }
])
//WARNING: I haven't tested this query, this is just to show the approach -> group based on votes.option and count all votes for that option for each document and then create optionsVote field by pushing all option with their count using $push into the field `optionsVote`
```

I recommend approach A because I assume POST operations would be quite less than GET operations. Also it's easier to implement. Having said that, keeping query in B handy will help you with sanity check.